# How to do something only for the first item in aray

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm currently looking for a way to designate the first item from the array. Let just say add different `className` only for the first `node` like example below

```js
export const ListQuery = graphql `
  query{
     list: allMarkdownRemark {
          edges {
               node {
                   id
               }
          }
     }          
  }

`
const Foo = (props) => {
   return (
      <>
         {props.data.list.edges.map((edge) => {
             <div clasName={edge.node[0]  ? `foo` : `bar`}>
                {edge.node.id} 
             </div>
         })}
      </>
   )
}
export default Foo;
```

i already try a ternary `{edge.node[0]  ? 'foo' : 'bar'}` but unfortunately doesn't seem to work

Comment: The map callback takes an index as second parameter. Does this help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
const Foo = (props) => {
   return (
      <>
         {props.data.list.edges.map((edge, i) => {
             <div className={i === 0  ? `foo` : `bar`}>
                {edge.node.id} 
             </div>  
         })}
      </>
   )
}
```